# What do you call a set of numbers between an upper and lower number?

Tags: general-topology, upper-lower-bounds, convention

A single number is referred to as a midpoint.  Is there a word that is used to refer to the range of numbers between two numbers?

For example for 1 and 5.

What would 2,3,4 be called when referring to numbers outside of the band like 6,7,8 or 0,-1,-2 etc...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: An open interval?

$(a,b) \subseteq \mathbb{Z} = \{a+1, a+2, \ldots, b-2, b-1\}$

Comment: Change "numbers" to "integers" in your title if that's what you meant. Had you wanted real numbers, the answer would be interval (open interval, in fact, if the endpoints were excluded).

Comment: "A single number is referred to as a midpoint."  Now always.  $1< 3< 9$ but no-one claims three is a midpoint.  I'd say "intermediary points".....

Comment: @InterstellarProbe  Did you mean to write "$\subseteq$" rather then "$\cap$"?

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I meant $\cap$. Sorry about that.

Comment: Actually, $(a,b) \cap \mathbb{Z} = \{\lfloor a+1 \rfloor, \lfloor a+2 \rfloor, \ldots, \lceil b-2 \rceil, \lceil b-1 \rceil \}$.

Still, the point is that an open interval is probable a good term for it.

Comment: Add as answer and I will mark it.